# Using Floating Action Button in Android

Tags: android

I've added an XML with the following code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      app:elevation="6dp"
      app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

I'm getting an error :

```
Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

Do I need to add some external library(.jar) ?

Comment: add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` custom name space

Comment: no just add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Thanks.
It's still not working though..

Comment: you have to add design support library.

Comment: Can you please explain what it means? Is it a certain .jar file?

Comment: It's a parsing error, so it has nothing to do with libraries. You need both `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` because both the android: and the app: prefixes have to be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you added below line in `build.gradle` ? :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

}
```

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse, not Android Studio..
I don't think I can do that, at least as far as I know there aren't gradles there

Comment: ok then go to this path \\android-sdk\extras\android\support\design and use that library.

Comment: I added that .jar that I found there to Libs folder in the project. Still getting error..
Also tried importing the folder and marking it as a library and add it in project's properties

Comment: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: check build path whether `Android Private Libraries` is checked in order and export or not. I tried this and it is working fine after adding that jar file to `libs`, please also clean your project.

Comment: You need the whole library project, no just the JAR.